# Error TypeError: roadHouse.isRunning is not a function when using custom TypeScript class

Tags: typescript, electron

I'm creating a custom Typescript class in my Electron project and I'm having getting errors when I call a method.

Class:

```
export class RoadHouse extends Object {
   public status: string = "ready";
   private _output: string = "";
   readonly startTime = Date.now();
   private running: boolean = false;

   constructor(private _message: String = "", private _prompt: String = "") {
       //this.setStatus(_message);
   }

   handleError(message: RoadHouse | string): void {
       this.setStatus("Status.Failed");
       if (message) {
          // 
       }
   }

   isRunning(): boolean {
       return this.running; // breakpoint set here
   }

   setStatus(value: string) {
       this._output = value;
   }

   start():void {
       this.running = true;
   }

   stop():void {
       this.running = false;
   }
}
```

In main.ts:

```
var roadHouse:RoadHouse = new RoadHouse("Hello");
console.log("Is running:" + roadHouse.isRunning());
```

Error:

> (node:18454) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: roadHouse.isRunning is not a function

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "strictNullChecks":false
  }
}
```

Build Task:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "Build Typescript",
            "command": "tsc"
        }
    ]
}
```

Package.json:

```
{
  "name": "typescript-electron",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Electron and Typescript",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "start electron ."
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron": "^5.0.3"
  }
}
```

Comment: Your code looks right. I made this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/magical-elgamal-dlt11) with your code and it does not throw an error. Is there any code that you have not showed that could be relevant?

Comment: @mgarcia I added the tsconfig.json and the build task if it helps

Comment: @mgarcia It looks like I had a typo and had `extends Object` in my class. I updated my post. It looks like that was the problem. It works if I remove that.

Comment: Mmmm, I don't understand why it's necessary to extend from `Object` in your example, but if you really need to extend from `Object` maybe the problem is that you are not calling `super` in the constructor.

Comment: @mgarcia When I was extending from Object I had added in the call to super. I was surprised that it caused problems when extending from Object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The class was extending Object. When I removed that it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can set debugger in the line you want to debug and press F12 but your code work normally.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zpd9bp